# How to set ComboBox to not show a part of string in it's items?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Want to keep track of some data for each insertion into `ComboBox` which data type is string. So I thought it's good idea to merge item text with my data.
However I need a way to hide the data from the items list.

Here is some a simple example of what I want:

```
"First item text             Data:This was a dog"
"Second item text            Data:This was a girl"
"...item text...             Data:...."
```

I need to find a solution to hide data from user.
Already tried to set `MaxLength` of ComboBox to 20 with no success.
**Note : I am not allowed to use any other class to achieve this so Stack, Queue won't help**

Comment: what about setting the width of the `Control`?

Comment: @Desolator I'll try now

Comment: @Desolator Can't do that.. still when client click on list item the data show up. it is also selectable.

Comment: Can you bind a vb.net combo box to an object as you can in C#? Then you have have one property as your display value and another as the data value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two attributes of each item in c# combo box are text and value. set item value to Data you want and text to string you want to display for your user.

```
mycomboBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("Value To Display", "actual value"));
mycomboBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("First item text", "This was a dog"));
```

Comment: It's a windows application not web.

Comment: Here is how we bind data. you can create datetable and fill it by looping over your data then bind it to combobox

Comment: cboStudents.DataSource = tblstudent;
cboStudents.ValueMember = "RollNumber";
cboStudents.DisplayMember = "StudentName";

Comment: Now there is an option for SelectedText and SelectedValue

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Lets consider this simple approach:

```
For i = 0 to n
   set combobox[i] to substring(0, m)
```

So that every item is just a substring containing the appreciated text to appear.

If the item was `"First item text             Data:This was a dog"`, for example, then this code shows only the part `"First item text"`: **(in C#)**

```
string str = "First item text             Data:This was a dog";
string shown = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("text") + 4);
string hidden = str.Substring(shown.Length);
```

And simply handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to update the UI with the data of the selected item.

```
private readonly string[] data = new[] { "This was a dog", "This was a girl" };
```

and then show data[comboBox.SelectedIndex]

Comment: Then I have to use some other class to store hidden text for each item.

Comment: @Mahdi No. You just need an array declared as a field member. I have update the answer